# Merge sort not working for ascending order

Tags: list, algorithm, scala, math, functional-programming

I am studying a course on scala in which I am performing merge sort operation. Here is the code written for that

```
def merge(leftList:List[Int], rightList:List[Int]): List[Int] = {

  val output = (0 until leftList.length + rightList.length).foldLeft(List[Int](), leftList, rightList) { (triple, _) =>
    val (mergedList, leftRemaining, rightRemaining) = triple
    (leftRemaining, rightRemaining) match {
      case (Nil, r :: rTail) => (r :: mergedList, Nil, rTail)
      case (l :: lTail, Nil) => (l :: mergedList, lTail, Nil)
      case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) if l > r => (l :: mergedList, lTail, rightRemaining)
      case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) => (r :: mergedList, leftRemaining, rTail)
    }
  }
  output._1.reverse
}

def mergeSort(inputList: IndexedSeq[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if(inputList.length == 1) List(inputList.head)
  else {
    val (leftList, rightList) = inputList.splitAt(inputList.length / 2)
    val sortedLeft = mergeSort(leftList)
    val sortedRight = mergeSort(rightList)
    merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
  }
}

mergeSort(Vector(3,4,1,2,33))
```

However, instead of the list getting sorted in ascending order, the list is always getting sorted in descending order. I tried debugging the code but did not come to any conclusion. Any help will be highly appreciated.
My current output is as follows

```
res0: List[Int] = List(33, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

expected output is

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 33)
```

Comment: change .reverse with sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. You have to only change (l > r) to (l < r) and that solves your problem.

Please refer following code

```
def merge(leftList:List[Int], rightList:List[Int]): List[Int] = {

  val output = (0 until leftList.length + rightList.length).foldLeft(List[Int](), leftList, rightList) { (triple, _) =>
    val (mergedList, leftRemaining, rightRemaining) = triple
    (leftRemaining, rightRemaining) match {
      case (Nil, r :: rTail) => (r :: mergedList, Nil, rTail)
      case (l :: lTail, Nil) => (l :: mergedList, lTail, Nil)
      case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) if l < r => (l :: mergedList, lTail, rightRemaining)
      case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) => (r :: mergedList, leftRemaining, rTail)
    }
  }
  output._1.reverse
}

def mergeSort(inputList: IndexedSeq[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if(inputList.length == 1) List(inputList.head)
  else {
    val (leftList, rightList) = inputList.splitAt(inputList.length / 2)
    val sortedLeft = mergeSort(leftList)
    val sortedRight = mergeSort(rightList)
    merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
  }
}
```

This produces output in the desired format

```
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 33)
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because here:

```
case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) if l > r => (l :: mergedList, lTail, rightRemaining)
```

you're placing on the first position `l` if it's greater than `r`. It should be reversed, if you want ascending order:

```
case (l :: lTail, r :: rTail) if l <= r => (l :: mergedList, lTail, rightRemaining)
```